# Text should change color after @ or #

Tags: html, css, colors

I have to do an assignment where I should create a code to look like an instagrampost. I have created the code, but I was wondering if there is a way (using CSS) to make text after @ or # turn blue. I'm of course thinking of the tags, which have to be blue. Right now I'm just using a font color-tag and turning the tags blue manually, but I want them to do it automatically every time a # or @ is written. Is there a way to do this? So each time a @ or # is written, the text after the symbols will turn blue?